# MacBook power cable with mounting holes

Tags: macbook-pro, power

my question is, if there is MacBook power cable with mounting holes. I think better picture than thousand words, I mean this power cable end:

[image: Macbook power cable]

with mounting holes, somehow like this:

[image: Power cord with mounting holes]

Comment: The power cable is a common Philips plug. You can buy these for a dollar and fix your own custom plug.

Comment: eBay, saddle-clips - http://www.ebay.co.uk/bhp/saddle-clips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple doesn't make that and I'd bet no one else does as well. Why not fabricate a bracket to physically go over the part you need and fasten it thusly?